# Why is the Highcharts tick placement different in two similar charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, formatting, styling

I have a question regarding the tick placement in two similar Highcharts chart. In the first example, I have specified the `xAxis` property and in the second example I have specified an `x` and `y` value in the series. The data is exactly the same, but as you can see the ticks are placed differently. I have tried to play around with the `tickmarkPlacement`, `minPadding`, `maxPadding` to make the first example look like the second, but without success.

Could someone tell me wy the two charts, place ticks so different and how I could make the first example look like the second example?

The code and jsFiddles:

## First Example

The code:

```
$('#container').highcharts(
    {
        "series": [
            {
                "name": "Series 1",
                "data": [
                    69.78,
                    2235.83,
                    69.78,
                    908.36,
                    69.78,
                    174.78
                ],
                "color": "#0084cb",
                "opposite": false
            }
        ],
        "xAxis": {
            "categories": [
                "2015",
                "2016",
                "2017",
                "2018",
                "2019",
                "2020"
            ],
            "tickmarkPlacement": "on"
        }
    }
);
```

The chart:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/fw9o4fjh/5/

## Second Example

The code:

```
$('#container').highcharts(
    {
        "series": [
            {
                "name": "Series 1",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "y": 69.78,
                        "x": 2015
                    },
                    {
                        "y": 2235.83,
                        "x": 2016
                    },
                    {
                        "y": 69.78,
                        "x": 2017
                    },
                    {
                        "y": 908.36,
                        "x": 2018
                    },
                    {
                        "y": 69.78,
                        "x": 2019
                    },
                    {
                        "y": 174.78,
                        "x": 2020
                    }
                ],
                "color": "#0084cb",
                "opposite": false
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

The chart:
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/y71f7hhd/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is a categorical axis type vs a linear axis type.

The categorical axis type reserves an even block of space for each category, which is why you see 'extra' space at the start and end of the x axis.

If you enable `crosshairs` on the chart, and hover over a point, you will see a good illustration of how it treats the axis spacing:

- categories: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/fw9o4fjh/6/
- linear: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/y71f7hhd/5/

One of the things you can do to manipulate the categorical axis the way you want is to use the min and the max, like this:

```
xAxis: {
  min:0.4,
  max:4.6,
  ...
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/fw9o4fjh/8/

It's far from exact, or ideal, but the categories work the way they do for logical reasons, and if you want your chart to plot like the linear example, the best thing to do is use a linear axis - or, since you're talking about dates, use a `datetime` axis type.

In either case, you can use the `pointStart` and `pointInterval` properties to avoid having to send the x value in your data.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/fw9o4fjh/10/

Comment: While some might say `datetime` axis is "harder" due to having to convert in some way the timestamp to js time it always ends up looking much cleaner and HC has built-in tools to handle dates much better than user trying to force dates as categories.

Comment: nice Explanation!! +1

Comment: @wergeld agreed. Early on, I avoided datetime axes because they seemed complicated. Once I dove in, I realized they're quite easy, usually, and provide a much better experience.

Comment: A very simple example with a datetime axis to get the ball rolling: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/fw9o4fjh/11/

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, this gives me some better insight in how Highcharts handles data.

Comment: @jlbriggs Ps: Is it not at all possible to switch the axis from categorical to linear?

Comment: @Waterstraal I guess that depends on what you mean - switch in what sense - by user interaction? By changing your chart options? You can do both.  Switch for what purpose? What's your overall end goal?

Comment: @jlbriggs I meant by setting a chart option to set the axis type

Comment: @Waterstraal - I don't understand the question then. Of course it's possible - my answer shows an example of categorical, and of linear.

Comment: No, the two are mutually exclusive. You have either categories, or a linear axis type, not both. You must use one of the other methods - either supply the x values in your data array, or use the pointStart and pointInterval properties.

Answer (score -1):

The different tick placement is because you've used 'xAxis' for the first chart and 'data' for the second. Change the charts so they're both using the same data method and they should look the same.

Comment: I use series.data in both cases, so I'm not sure what you mean. Could you please update the fiddle and show me what you mean? Thanks!

Comment: In the first chart you specify categories for the x axis. In the second chart you specify the x value in data. This is why highcharts is generating the charts differently. You need to use the same method of setting the x axis for both charts if possible.