# Change first tick position on xAxis

Tags: highcharts

This is my chart

[image: chart]

I need that tick start from the start of my chart, without padding left.

I tried read docs, but I couldn't find anything about it

Comment: look at minPadding. if that doesn't do it, post a live fiddle of your chart, or at least the code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ns4txh0f/ this is my code, yes, i tried minpadding

Comment: See my answer here on why the categorical axis doesn't behave in the way you're expecting:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653678/why-is-the-highcharts-tick-placement-different-in-two-similar-charts/34656442#34656442  And then follow wergeld's answer below for how to move forward with it

Comment: if i need not years, i need my own timestamps

Comment: A datetime axis will display whatever units of time you provide to it.

Comment: You can set min/max values http://jsfiddle.net/yfjvngo1/, but better is using datetime type of xAxis, as other users suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs it should be doing this anyway with [`xAxis.startOnTick`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.startOnTick):

```
Whether to force the axis to start on a tick.
Use this option with the minPadding option to control the axis start.
Defaults to false.
```

So, perhaps you overwrote this in your chart code?

**Update:**
So, from your code what you have is a categorical xAxis and an area line chart. Stylistically* this does not make much sense as the entire category "bin" is one single value and you are putting in time values (I assume since they are `['00:00', '05:00', '05:00', '05:00', '05:00']`). Why not make an actual time series xAxis? This would give discrete x positions based upon the time and you could see that area chart a bit clearer.

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/os4nx2Lg/) time-based xAxis:

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'area'
    },
    xAxis: {
      startOnTick: false,
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'John',
      data: [0, 3, 4, 7, 2],
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 0),
      pointInterval: 5 * 3600 * 1000 // 5 hour
    }, {
      name: 'Jane',
      data: [2, -2, -3, 2, 1],
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 0),
      pointInterval: 5 * 3600 * 1000 // 5 hour
    }, {
      name: 'Joe',
      data: [3, 4, 4, -2, 5],
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 0),
      pointInterval: 5 * 3600 * 1000 // 5 hour
    }]
  });
});
```

- What I mean "stylistically" is that you have hard breaks from "00:00" to "05:00". So let's assume that is 5 hours between categories. Does an area plot really convey any information to the user since you have a 5 hour gap between points? Wouldn't a simply column chart make more sense here? If this is even 5 minutes between categories it seems a little iffy to make this an area chart.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/ns4txh0f this is my code, yes, i tried minpadding

Comment: i need every 5 min, not 5 hour

Comment: You can adjust the `pointInterval`. The 5 minute would be `300 * 1000`.

Comment: can i change color of area if >0 GREEN if <0 RED?